# Can an inferred return type be named?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function:

```
function getStudent() {
  return {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 18,
  }
}
```

I can define a type based on the return value:

```
type Student = ReturnType<typeof getStudent>;
```

However when I hover over the function call or `student` below:

```
const student = getStudent();
```

they have the type:

```
{
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  age: number,
}
```

But I would prefer that they be typed `Student`. While the inferred type is useful, sometimes it is more useful to know that a particular object was returned by a specific function. This is because many functions actually only return a subset of the infered types, in fact to my knowledge the type system can not even describe a constraint like age > 0.

So ideally there would be a way to define the `Student` type so that given a function like:

```
function passStudent(student: Student) {
  // ...
}
```

The following would be ok:

```
passStudent(getStudent());
```

but not the following:

```
passStudent({
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 18,
});
```

Which would produce an error. I'm not sure this is a feature that exists in TypeScript or if it is in line with TypeScript's design philosophy. But it would be nice. Does it exist?

I actually do have some code that gets me halfway there, but it adds runtime overhead. I'll post it as an answer since it might help someone else but it's not what I am looking for. Other attempts have resulted in circular definition errors.

I kind of expect this to not exist and I will make a feature request if this is the case. I'm looking for some syntax like:

```
function getStudent(): infer Student {
```

or

```
type Student = ReturnType<typeof student as const>;
```

Comment: You're doing this backwards, write the `Student` interface then the compiler can actually check the implementation. But fundamentally TypeScript is structurally, not nominally, typed (see e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html), and even in nominally typed languages it doesn't matter where a value comes from as long as it has the right type (because why would you care? Why make it harder to e.g. write tests?)

Comment: In a structural typing system, it wouldn't be "nice" if the compiler accepts `pass(o1)` but rejects `pass(o2)` when `o1` and `o2` are structurally identical. If you file that part as a feature request it'll be rejected or closed as a duplicate of [ms/TS#202](//github.com/Microsoft/Typescript/issues/202), and you'll be told to use workarounds like branding. If you care about the *display* of the type (a separate issue) you could make `Student` an interface like [this](//tsplay.dev/wezgEN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've already mentioned in the question a good reason. I can as a human read the code and see that `getStudent().age` is always a positive integer, TypeScript can not describe this constraint. There are also lots of constraints that take too much effort to describe, or too much processing power and others that only can be checked at runtime

Comment: Wait, I'm a human (I think) and I don't see how you can determine that `age` is always a positive integer; where is that information encoded?

Comment: @jcalz I mean in this example its actually always 18, but here is another example: `age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 15`. Here as a human I can tell that age is between 15 and 20, good luck getting the typesytstem to determine that.

Comment: Right, so this really feels like you want classes with private members, since that's one of the few places in TypeScript that actually cares about provenance and not just structure.  Presumably you wouldn't actually be happy if the compiler *could* type `Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+15` as `15|16|17|18|19` and then accept an external value with the right age; you really want to enforce that it came from that particular implementation.

Comment: @jcalz Oh right, classes, I totally forgot those existed. I'm not sure what private members have to do with it, but an old fashioned constructor seems like it would fit the bill.

Comment: Without a private/protected member you can still pass a structurally-identical value in.  I'm happy to write up an answer explaining this if you'd like to see one and are likely to accept it.  How shall I proceed?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah sure, looks like it would fit the bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're really looking for here is a [*nominal type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), where only values of the type *named* `Student` (or a type from the same type *declaration*) are allowed.  But TypeScript's type system is largely [*structural*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not nominal.  If two object types have the same members, then they are the same type:

```
interface Student {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
}
const student: Student = {
    firstName: "abc", lastName: "def", age: 123
};

interface Master {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
}
const master: Master = student; // okay
// the student has become the master!!
```

This is intentional behavior of TypeScript, and quite different from the behavior of other popular typed languages.  If you find yourself wanting it to be different, you might spend some time figuring out if you can work *with* this system before trying to work *against* it.  If there's a reason for two types to be distinct, can you represent that difference *structurally*?  Maybe one should have a method that the other one doesn't?  You might be happier if you can do this.

---

Still, sometimes people really do want nominal types.  TypeScript has a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#202](https://github.com/Microsoft/Typescript/issues/202), and a lot of people want to see it happen.  And there are a few techniques you can use to simulate/emulate them.

You could add a "brand" member as described in [the TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible), which makes it less likely to accidentally match another type.  But it can still happen.

Going further, though, you can use [a `class` with a `private` member](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private) for this purpose.  This is sort of an "un-copyable" brand; [`private` and `protected` class members are compared *nominally* and not *structurally*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes).  So if you do this, you'll get the behavior you're looking for:

```
class Student {
    firstName = "John";
    lastName = "Doe";
    age = 18;
    private readonly __type = "Student"
}
function passStudent(student: Student) { }

const student = new Student();
passStudent(student); // okay
passStudent(new Student()); // okay
passStudent({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 18,
    __type: "Student"
}); // error!

/*   Property '__type' is private in type 'Student' but not in type
 '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number; __type: "Student"; }'.
  */
```

Here, the object literal passed in is structurally identical to `Student` but the compiler still complains, because `__type` is `private` in `Student`.  Even another class with a `private` member will be rejected:

```
class Impostor {
    firstName = "John";
    lastName = "Doe";
    age = 18;
    private readonly __type = "Student" // 
}
passStudent(new Impostor()); // error!
// Types have separate declarations of a private property '__type'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAZUlAKgTzrFAb2BVJQEsQAXKAJwDMlU0qBXAEymqJLL-vK0YVAHKYAXCmG1KAcwDcvPqQA2YYWOiTpcxcrJhZUSSFYQARnT1kAvkpSIA9iGFS2napJYcuVFAF4efVIBIVEJFAAiMHNESIAaFDUNCMjOegSUQ2MUAEYAJgBmextFe0oaBiYUAFl1SqDg0JStNxkQBXs+ZPDWnQ7rfWyTM0taQZQ7PicXPwh6ukk64ToAtx9qeRQAem2URwBrMBx7XZQqAAtUYQ2-C-UUSydoc6uUeZXaAEIv4DtgYCIZIwdDuXyNEKCFqoQKRABSjguIEiEx6mhhUQAIo4oCj7Nk1rkABwTOAyABuYBoKFoUDA7GcKhwKAA+iyqHgMZFvB4qJE-sB6KwQIgqORnCgEDAYDzfAAKG68rxg6gASiIkwBM1civBgRAUAA7qDbnLVYopTKVVQFdbzTs9odjsBLbLqHKDca3TbVfazk6Tq7rXLiPwob0cvDEcj4vY0alsbjY3xhnkicmyGyOfhJNzrfybH69nRaI5vgDtgAqMgABVL+FoHJQAHIs5zmxQQWTyJTqZRzpyW96O+ZWH4QI4-P3s1ASM3CChmhHtFR2gokvV0Su11tU6YLFZWezObnvSjJs2AHS8SvbAGA4EoACSEDgjmEZYhi-D6LWUaReLdJumB-omgEGEYhIkvY3a9qgtL0oyzJtvgf5ng6KCALwbgAQewKQamp6z6vu+VBlmaRYoCWZa-GcuD4CC9zktcUAILQVKoJwQJgGxYrOCCjj0FkkoUuxwmOA2Tatse+BXsAQA)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using a type assertion to explicitly specify the return type of `getStudent` as `Student`. This will ensure that any variable or function parameter that is typed asStudent`will only accept values that match the shape of the`Student` type.

```
type Student = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
}

function getStudent(): Student {
  return {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 18,
  };
}

function passStudent(student: Student) {
  console.log(student.firstName, student.lastName);
}

const student = getStudent() as Student;
passStudent(student);
```

Comment: How does this help? Firstly a type assertion _doesn't_ ensure that the value matches the type, and secondly this _doesn't_ prevent `passStudent({ firstName: "", lastName: "", age: 0 })`.

Answer (score 0):

Something that almost seems like it works is a wrapper function:

```
function _getStudent() {
  return {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 18,
  }
}

type Student = ReturnType<typeof _getStudent> & { __type: "Student" };

function getStudent(): Student {
  const student = _getStudent() as Student
  student.__type = "Student";
  return student;
}
```

[see in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=1&pln=43&pc=31#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAfQOYFMoGUogCbphQAUAlIgN4BQiiATpiHUtbbcDHQM5QByAhgFt0ALkQAiAFJwAFmHEAaGmwA2-HgOFjxAETjpFy2vwxiAjAA4ltAL5U7VKAE8ADukQ58hKIgC8iACVGZgAVV3QAHmc3OGAUDGxcAiIAPkQAMkoUZGjRCU9kqHFEGwBuKipQSFgERASC7zIxBqJKZQgEHkQeL1b-NEwWknJ1DyTvZR7CgDpkHPC-fPGicXLaBlxmbuWococOsC7kKe9FgcTe4fKDrpO+usGdsmvOnx46EGhF1kQObj4hHkpLJ5NZEGoNIDtHoDGCTHlLEo7DcfLk8DgPl9-D9prj3p8oGC5rltENxPYqCjEB10HQIOh0VBMT5-GiMQTEKMhpTXogXHQ4G46M4AML6bjwJDY5S46b46BE+ZuUk7YqjcRkimVcDQSV89RcIbEO5QZo7cg-DZMJBMkDoPYVFwGo3Hc3lJ1cQ1PE2kd3O7226C+qger2XYhswNQYOho00ukM9lBv2eo38wW00XiriS31AA)

We can test this as follows:

```
const _student = _getStudent();
const student = getStudent();
const struct = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 18,
}
const typedStruct = {
  ...struct,
  __type: "Student"
}
const coercedStruct = typedStruct as Student
const propertyCoersion = {
  ...struct,
  __type: "Student" as "Student"
}

function passStudent(student: Student) {
  return true;
}

passStudent(_student);
passStudent(student);
passStudent(struct);
passStudent(typedStruct);
passStudent(coercedStruct);
passStudent(propertyCoersion);
```

[see in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=1&pln=43&pc=31#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAfQOYFMoGUogCbphQAUAlIgN4BQiiATpiHUtbbcDHQM5QByAhgFt0ALkQAiAFJwAFmHEAaGmwA2-HgOFjxAETjpFy2vwxiAjAA4ltAL5U7VKAE8ADukQ58hKIgC8iACVGZgAVV3QAHmc3OGAUDGxcAiIAPkQAMkoUZGjRCU9kqHFEGwBuKipQSFgERASC7zIxBqJKZQgEHkQeL1b-NEwWknJ1DyTvZR7CgDpkHPC-fPGicXLaBlxmbuWococOsC7kKe9FgcTe4fKDrpO+usGdsmvOnx46EGhF1kQObj4hHkpLJ5NZEGoNIDtHoDGCTHlLEo7DcfLk8DgPl9-D9prj3p8oGC5rltENxPYqCjEB10HQIOh0VBMT5-GiMQTEKMhpTXogXHQ4G46M4AML6bjwJDY5S46b46BE+ZuUk7YqjcRkimVcDQSV89RcIbEO5QZo7cg-DZMJBMkDoPYVFwGo3Hc3lJ1cQ1PE2kd3O7226C+qger2XYhswNQYOho00ukM9lBv2eo38wW00XiriS31AA)

The tests above pass fine. But as pointed out by jonrsharpe in the comments, the following will not behave as expected:

```
passStudent({
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 18,
  __type: "Student",
});
```

And I quote:

> It will work, the narrower type is inferred for the inlined object because it can't be mutated before the function is called: tsplay.dev/WG8avw. It wouldn't work if you assigned it to a variable and then called the function with that...

However, if you do not mind the overhead of an additional function call you can combine the wrapper approach with the class with private brand approach as expounded by jcalz in the answer I've accepted.

This has the added benefit that you can encapsulate the smelly throw catch block that the class based approach forces you into for validation:

```
class JWT {
  private __type = "JWT";
  public header: JWTHeader;
  public payload: JWTPayload;
  public signature: string;
 
  constructor(public token: string) {
    if(!isValidJWT(token)) throw "Invalid JWT";
    //...
  }

  //...

  toString() {
    return this.token;
  }
}

function parseJWT(input: string): JWT | null {
  try {
    return new JWT(input)
  } catch (error) {
    if(error === "Invalid JWT") return null;
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: But why would you? You can still trivially `passStudent({ firstName: "", lastName: "", age: 0, __type: "Student" })`. What's the context, why is it valuable to pass _"the return value from `getStudent`"_ rather than just _"a `Student`"_?

Comment: Actually that wont work since `__type` will be infered as `string`, however `passStudent({ firstName: "", lastName: "", age: 0, __type: "Student" as "Student"})` or `passStudent({ firstName: "", lastName: "", age: 0, __type: "Student" } as Student)` will

Comment: It will work, the narrower type is inferred for the inlined object because it can't be mutated before the function is called: https://tsplay.dev/WG8avw. It wouldn't work if you assigned it to a variable and then called the function with that, but as you point out it can trivially be worked around (and for that matter if we're allowing type assertions `passStudent({} as Student)` works just fine).

Comment: If you're willing to do this you might want to consider using `private` class members instead, which is a place TS naturally treats as nominal, as seen [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NnExxw).  Does that work for your purposes?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ohh... my bad. I guess the answer is worse than I thought.